# How to enable keep alive in ios CFSocket?

Tags: ios, keep-alive, cfsocket

How can i enable keep alive in ios app   (CFSocket class).

Comment: if there is any methods to check the server is alive like keep alive mechanism

Comment: int enable = 1; setsockopt(CFSocketGetNative(TCPClient),SOL_SOCKET,SO_KEEPALIVE,&enable,sizeof(enable)));                                                 Upon successful completion, the value 0 is returned; otherwise the value -1 is returned .